# Laravel For Each Loop in Has Many only returns one record

Tags: php, laravel-5

I currently have two models setup:
Categories and Main Categories:
My Categories model has:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\MainCategory');
```

My Main Categories model has:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'main_category_id');
```

In my controller I get the main category data like so:

```
$mainCategory = MainCategory::all();

return view('layouts.categories', ['mainCategory' => $mainCategory]);
```

In my blade I try to access each main category and it's sub categories like this:

```
                <aside id="sidebar_cate" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
                    <h3 class="sidebar-title">Category</h3>
                @foreach ($mainCategory as $mCat)
                    <ul id="cate_list" class="cate_list">
                        <li class="level0 parent">
                            <a href="#" title="Business Cards">
                                <span>{{ $mCat->category_name }}</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                                @foreach ($mCat->categories as $category)
                            <ul class="level0">
                                <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first item">
                                    <a href="#" title="Premium Business Cards">
                                        {{ $category->title }}
                                        <span class="count-item">(22)</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            @endforeach
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    @endforeach
```

The for each `@foreach ($mCat->categories as $category)`

only returns one record when the database has multiple records with the related key.  I was expecting it to return each record.

```
Expected results:
Main Category
   Category 1 (has key that matches main category)
   Category 2 (has key that matches main category)
   Category 1 (has key that matches main category)
2nd Main Category
   Category 1 (has key that matches main category2)
   Category 2 (has key that matches main category2)
   Category 1 (has key that matches main category2)
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the expected categories in `dd($mainCategory[0]->categories);`?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir dd($mainCategory[0]->categories); this returns the array.... 3 items as I would expect.  So what I do is that I put it in a foreach loop in the blade template: @foreach ($mCat->categories as $category) but then it only returns one.  I would expect it to return all 3.

Comment: What does `{{ $mCat->categories->count() }}` give you?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir in a for each it out puts the correct number of categories.  3, 1, 0, 0, 0.  That is correct as far as the items in the categories.

Comment: When you say "only returns one record": Is only one category visible on the website? Or does the HTML source actually only contain one category?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir  only one record per main category appears.  For example when we ran count() it said there is 3 but when I run the for each I get 1 category that appears.

Comment: But it's definitely not a CSS issue?

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir definitely not a CSS issue.

Comment: @ Jonas Staudenmeir  I can provide any other code that you need to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171359/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-fabriciog).